# Self reference in @Repository class result in circular reference

Tags: java, spring

I found that self reference in `@Repository` does not work, for example:

```java
@Repository
public class HelloService {
    static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    @Autowired
    HelloService self;  // <----- self reference
    ...
}
```

Got circular reference error

> o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloService': Bean with name 'helloService' has been injected into other beans [helloService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

However, this trick could work when change `Repository` to `@Component` or `@Service`. As a workaround, I have to put a `@Lazy` in `self`.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this?

Comment: We want to use `self` to access AOP method through proxy object instead of the target object. Even though it might be a bad practice, however, it is a quite simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your `HelloService` depends on how your Spring Data JPA repositories are being bootstrapped, which, in this case, seems to be DEFAULT mode:

> - DEFAULT (default) — Repositories are instantiated eagerly unless explicitly annotated with @Lazy.

Read logs, and look for this entry:

```java
RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in XYZ mode.
```

then see what is that XYZ.

[`@Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) helps you, because:

> If this annotation is not present on a @Component or @Bean definition, eager initialization will occur. If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory.

In order to understand how your other components are being initialized, better to have logs, properties, configuration, or anything else, that might affect the Spring application's behaviour. It's really difficult to guess what you have, if you don't provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

---

### Other points:

Generally, it's a very bad practice to inject `A` into `A`, and you should, pretty much, never do it.

However, if not `@Lazy` bean `A` is injected into itself, it's not a surprise that you will get an exception. You need to have a ready bean, in the Spring Container, in order to inject it somewhere; and, in order to get that bean ready, Spring must inject its dependencies.. yet, in your code:

```java
@Repository
public class HelloService {
    static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

    @Autowired
    HelloService self;  // <----- self reference
    ...
}
```

it depends on itself.

You're telling to the Application Context, to:

1. Instantiate bean `helloService` (which includes preparing it, by injecting its each dependency);
2. Inject `helloService` bean into itself.

Do you think `step 2` can be completed without first completing `step 1`? and how will `step 1` complete if `step 2` cannot complete?

You are injecting something that is *not ready*, and in order to get that ready, you need to inject it, *itself*, which is, again, not ready.. and so on..

which gets you to the Circular Reference problem, which is a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The project is a web application based on spring boot, not use JPA. Badly, I could not reproduce the issue with a simple demo

Comment: Regarding "Other points" part, yes, it is indeed a circular reference issue, but Spring could resolve it (when using field injection). As a proof, Use `@Component` or `@Service` instead, it works, no issue yet.

Comment: As a demo to show Spring could resolve this kind of circular reference (self reference), we could start with this project https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/. Put `HelloService` under the same path with `Application` class,  we could see that there is no circular reference issue occur.